# How to fix this binding error in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I have a view model with a property

```
public string ErrorMessage
```

in my XAML I have

```
 <TextBox Grid.Column="7" Text="{Binding Path=ErrorMesssage}"/>
```

and I get this error message

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : 
BindingExpression path error: 
'ErrorMesssage' property not found on 'object' 
''MoineauPumpCorrectionViewModel'
 (HashCode=27349565)'. BindingExpression:Path=ErrorMesssage; 
DataItem='MoineauPumpCorrectionViewModel' (HashCode=27349565);
 target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

Now the problem is this. I load up snoop to look at the data context of the TextBox

[image]

It is very clear that the datacontext is indeed my correct view model and it has the property `ErrorMessage` which in this case reads `cannot be empty` as I expect. So what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry bud but you spelt *ErrorMessage* wrong.

Lose the extra 's' :D

instead of this

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="7" Text="{Binding Path=ErrorMesssage}"/>
```

try this

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="7" Text="{Binding Path=ErrorMessage}"/>
```

Comment: Damn it. Not enough sleep. 3 sss's in a row. :)

Comment: @bradgonesurfing Clearly the wrong letter entirely! You need more Zs.